# A SciFi book about a kid trying to recover kingdom

Tags: story-identification, space

I'm trying to remember a book about a young man trying to get back his kingdom after being deposed and family is killed. It had a large military space station and a bit about where he gets a group of privateers to help him by raiding the royal treasury of old earth relics. Also some sort of prison system where the king is the only one who knows how to get to the planet.

He was in the military that served his father in some sort of large asteroid base, but they only see him as a figurehead.

Comment: When I first started reading your question, I thought it was a fantasy novel. But then you talk about space stations and it sounds like a sci-fi. Is it a blend of genres or is it purely sci-fi?

Comment: The story is pure Sci-Fi.

Comment: Perhaps explicitly saying that in the title and the first sentence or two would help.

Comment: When did you read it? Do you remember anything about the cover? Literally any additional details you add could help.

Comment: I do not remember any other details.  It was a very long time ago.  The one who is trying to get back his kingdom is maybe 18-25 years old, maybe younger.